# C# - How to Determine if a Configuration Section exists in a mapped EXE configuration file?

Tags: c#, configuration, configuration-files, configurationmanager

I have a C# project that is reading from a stand-alone configuration file named `test.config`. This is a *separate* file from the typical `App.config`.

I am trying to determine if the `test.config` file contains the optional property `TestProperty` from code. I attempted to use `TestProperty.ElementInformation.IsPresent` but this always results in a value of FLASE even when the section element is actually there.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string filePath = @"C:\Users\username\Desktop\TestProject\ConfigTestApp\Test.Config";
        ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap(filePath);
        fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = Path.GetFileName(filePath);

        Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        TestConfigSection section = config.GetSection("TestConfigSection") as TestConfigSection;
        bool isPresent = section.TestProperty.ElementInformation.IsPresent; // Why is this always false?
    }
}
```

The `test.config` file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name ="TestConfigSection" type ="ConfigTestApp.TestConfigSection, ConfigTestApp"/>
  </configSections>

  <TestConfigSection>
    <TestProperty testvalue="testing 123" />
  </TestConfigSection>
</configuration>
```

The backing classes are:

```
public class TestConfigSection : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("TestProperty", IsRequired = true)]
    public TestConfigElement TestProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return base["TestProperty"] as TestConfigElement;
        }
    }
}

public class TestConfigElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("testvalue", IsKey = true, IsRequired = true)]
    public string TestValue
    {
        get { return base["testvalue"] as string; }
        set { base["testvalue"] = value; }
    }
}
```

If I move the section into App.config and use `ConfigurationManager.GetSection("TestConfigSection")`, IsPresent seems to work fine, but I need this to work from a separate file (test.config).

Is there any way to get `TestProperty.ElementInformation` working or any other way to determine if the test.config file contains the `TestProperty` property?

Comment: I put this in a unit test, ran it, and it worked for me. That makes me wonder if you might have two versions of the file. You can inspect the `ElementInformation` or `SectionInformation` for other clues. This stuff used to give me insane grief. You might find it much easier to just read from a JSON file or something and save yourself the trouble, if that's an option.

Comment: Interesting, It worked even with the testconfigsection being placed in a separate xml config file? (I.e. - not in the app.config but in a separate file named test.config)

Comment: I used a variable so I had the right path for the FileMap. This is why I hate these classes. If they don't load I want an exception - not making it look like it loaded but the values are defaults. I'm sure they had their reasons, but it was a huge pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is your problem:

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap(filePath);
fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
```

Shouldn't `ExeConfigFilename` be the full path to the file like this?

```
fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = filePath;
```

If that is not the problem, I recently had to do something like you are doing and here is what I did (using your example data).

```
string filePath = @"C:\Users\username\Desktop\TestProject\ConfigTestApp\Test.Config";
ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap { ExeConfigFilename = filePath };
config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
AppSettingsSection section = (AppSettingsSection) config.GetSection("TestConfigSection");

if ( section != null )
{
  string testValue = section .Settings["TestProperty"].Value;
}
```

In my config file I used this type of format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <TestConfigSection file="">
    <clear />
    <add key="TestProperty" value="testing 123" />
  </TestConfigSection>
</configuration>
```

Comment: That was it! My problem was that I had set fileMap.ExeconfigFileName to the filename and not the full path+filename. Good catch, thanks!

Comment: ***Also, I need to add an important note: I should not have been calling the overload of `ExeConfigurationFileMap` which accepts a `string machineConfigFileName` AND simultaneously set `fileMap.ExeConfigFileName` at the same time! This was causing a bug in my code with an error of "The entry 'MyEntry' has already been added" I removed `ExeConfigurationFileMap(filePath)` and replaced with the default constructor and it worked fine after that.